# Unity Facebook SDK IOS 9.2 Not Returning to app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk, unity-game-engine

I started noticing that on IOS 9.2, using Unity Facebook Plugin 7.3.0 with the server and app white lists provided https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9#whitelistapp When I issue my login call it opens the login page like normal but never returns to the app and if i manually return to the app its returning that the user is not logged in. It sits at this screen. It also works correctly on android and previous ios versions, so its something with IOS 9.2[image]

Comment: Have you added the callback method and delegate to the app. Can you add some code snippets of how are you doing it.

Comment: @saral the login calls themselves have callbacks yes.  If there's something else I need to do in the native side that's not in unity that is different than previous I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone else that might have an issue with this.  One of the plugins used was using openURL in the native project and not returning the proper response. So thats why it wouldn't return nor the correct data was passed.

Comment: I have the same issue. The best way to examine this issue is to create an empty project and follow the official guide and test the functionality of "Login". If the "Hello project" works, check any libraries or plugins that you used in your project. In my case, the AppsFlyer library is causing the issue.